# Effect of mass on terminal velocity

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, fluid-dynamics, drag, viscosity

How does increasing the mass of heavy and light objects affect their terminal velocity in viscous and inertial drag?

Comment: -1. No research effort. You could at least look at the wikipedia article on [terminal velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_velocity).

Answer (score 0):

Drag is a force that acts on the object in the opposite direction of the objects motion. Drag increases with velocity (e.g. pressure drag $F_R \propto v^2$), hence, all else being equal, F is larger for a more massive object undergoing uniform acceleration so it has a higher terminal velocity (where $\mathbf F = -\mathbf F_R$).